# ksoap2 in Android: noclassdeffounderror on SoapObject

Tags: android, eclipse, ksoap2

I've added ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.5-jar-with-dependencies to my build path in eclipse and given internet permissions in the manifest.  The error is on: 'SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);' and is a noclassdeffounderror. I checked the references folder and there is definitely a class called SoapObject in the ksoap2 file. I'm using Eclipse Helios.  All of the other relevent posts I have seen don't appear to solve my version of this problem so any help would be greatly appriciated!

 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some frustration trying all of the solutions I could possibly find I had a "duh" moment.  I had imported the ksoap2 file as a zip and it occured to me that maybe android couldn't deal with it.  I imported the jar and it worked perfectly.